# cannot ping VMware Ubuntu machine from other machines in network (other than host machine)

Tags: networking, vmware-workstation

I am running an Ubuntu VMware image under VMware Workstation.  The host OS is Windows 7.

I can access the Internet from the guest.  I have my Windows firewall disabled; also, Windows Defender is turned off.

When I try to ping from the guest to the host and vice versa by IP it works fine.

Pinging any other machine from the guest by using IP also works fine.

But when I try to ping the guest from other machines in network it cannot be reached.  Any clues?

I found the IP of the guest by using ifconfig.

Checking properties of the VM, it says network adapter NAT :used to share hosts ip address.
This option is selected.

How can I ping the guest from other machines in network?

Answer (score 2):

You would have to change the adapter to bridged so that the vm can get an ip in your LAN. Or you need to have a way to forward the icmp traffic in your LAN to the vm.

Comment: I changed the setting to bridged , but i dint check "replicate physical network connection state" .And now i cant ping from vm to my host machine and vice versa.Also cant ping vm from any other machine in network.

Comment: Did you restart vm network and confirm that now it had an ip from your LAN?